# How can I make global custom fields (text, image, etc) for the template, editable from the admin panel?

Tags: wordpress

The only proper way I found is to use the ACF Pro plugin.
Is there any other FREE way how to do it?
Example use case: phone number or logo, which is present on all pages of the template, and should be editable in the admin panel.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You could set this up in numerous ways! I'd add an admin menu which accepts a form which submits and stores my data into the database. You could either build it into the theme, or you could develop a plugin which can be installed and run on any theme. No third party plugin(s) needed. Please be specific, add and explain exactly what you want so that people could go ahead and help you out. It'd be even better, if you could add what you've done so far to implement this.

Comment: How can I build custom fields into the theme? Can you suggest some manual? I even have no clue on how to search for it.

Comment: May be this can help you https://metabox.io/easy-way-to-add-custom-fields-in-wordpress-without-plugins/

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang I need custom fields for the whole site. Like phone number in the header or logo.

Comment: @TarasKudrych I couldn't get you. Can you update the question with screenshots as to where you need the fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the custom settings with either using plugin or using theme. I created custom settings fields with plugin and you can use and put required code into theme also. I created simple input field but you can create any of the field.

```
<?php

/*
 * Plugin Name: Register Custom Settings
 * Description: Adds custom setting field in admin.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Wordpress
 * Author uri: https://wordpress.org
 * Text Domain: register-custom-settings
*/

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Sample page', 'register-custom-settings' ),
        __( 'Sample menu', 'register-custom-settings' ),
        'manage_options',
        'sample-page',
        'my_admin_page_contents',
        'dashicons-schedule',
        3
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_page_contents() {
    ?>
    <h1> <?php esc_html_e( 'Welcome to my custom admin page.', 'register-custom-settings' ); ?> </h1>
    <form method="POST" action="options.php">
    <?php
    settings_fields( 'sample-page' );
    do_settings_sections( 'sample-page' );
    submit_button();
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_settings_init' );

function my_settings_init() {

    add_settings_section(
        'sample_page_setting_section',
        __( 'Custom settings', 'register-custom-settings' ),
        'my_setting_section_callback_function',
        'sample-page'
    );

        add_settings_field(
           'my_setting_field',
           __( 'My custom setting field', 'register-custom-settings' ),
           'my_setting_markup',
           'sample-page',
           'sample_page_setting_section'
        );

        register_setting( 'sample-page', 'my_setting_field' );
}


function my_setting_section_callback_function() {
    echo '<p>Intro text for our settings section</p>';
}


function my_setting_markup() {
    ?>
    <label for="my-input"><?php _e( 'My Input' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" id="my_setting_field" name="my_setting_field" value="<?php echo get_option( 'my_setting_field' ); ?>">
    <?php
}
```

After that you can get custom setting field data with `get_option( 'my_setting_field' );`

If you wish to create fields for templates and all requires to store different values for each templates than you needs to create the custom meta with "PAGE" post type which will display and store data into all page post type.
Here is the link for create [custom meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/)